# Remove slashes in node js mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

This is my code.

```
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query("delete from userFiles where type = 1 and 
                          typeId = " + taskId + " and fileName 
                          NOT IN ('?') ",[oldFileNames], function (err, rows) {

        });
    });
```

Now the problem is , node js is generating query like this,

```
delete from table_name where type = 1 and typeId = 1 and 
fileName NOT IN (\'\'upload_149f2b78e5fd4096781bb5b8719b874f.png,upload_e8185e896cb0f8bb0b66d807cc60922c.png\'\')
```

I even tried like this,

```
connection.query("delete from userFiles where type = 1 and typeId = " + taskId + " and
                    fileName NOT IN ('" + oldFileNames + "') ", 
                      function (err, rows) {
```

This generated query like this,

```
delete from userFiles where type = 1 and typeId = 1 and 
fileName NOT IN (\'upload_149f2b78e5fd4096781bb5b8719b874f.png,
upload_e8185e896cb0f8bb0b66d807cc60922c.png\')
```

Both are causing `mysql` syntax error for the query(slashes are getting appended).

Can you suggest, what i can do to get rid of this error.

Comment: What's oldFileNames ? An array or a string ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret its a comma separated value from form.

Comment: OK, It should be an array. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to add the quotes yourself around the `?` placeholder. Remove them.

You should also pass an array, not a string. Assuming it's a clean string, you can just use `split`.

```
connection.query(
      "delete from userFiles where type = 1 and typeId = " + taskId +
      " and fileName NOT IN (?) ", [oldFileNames.split(/,\s*/)],
      function (err, rows) {
```

Comment: I got like this, `delete from userFiles where type = 1 and typeId = 1 and fileName NOT IN (\'upload_d46d172a7aaabf50f7598a334cc2ce37.png,upload_b008eaa4f8731bfab7d3aec3614cf15e.png\')`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju It looks like your `oldFileNames` string contains quotes, and that's a problem. Can you look at that ?

Comment: Nope... im passing only comma separated names.

Comment: And above query is deleting all rows.

Comment: What's oldFileNames ? An array or a string ? An array is needed, not a string.

Comment: @Denys ...can you solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633511/unwanted-backslash-appears-in-query-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use connection.escape();

```
connection.query("delete from userFiles where type = 1 and typeId = " + taskId + " 
and fileName NOT IN (" + connection.escape(oldFileNames) + ")");
```

Comment: none of the rows r getting deleted even if there r some rows.

Comment: this only works when oldFileNames is an array of strings.