# How to use connection.escape in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, backslash

I am facing an issue in my query that I generate in NodeJs. The query that gets generated has '\' backslash appended to it. Similar to the question mentioned here -

[Remove slashes in node js mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561437/remove-slashes-in-node-js-mysql-query)

So a solution mentioned is using

```
 connection.escape(stringValue)
```

However, I am facing difficulty in using connection.escape. I get error -

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): TypeError: connection.escape is not a function
```

I understand that we need a connection. So I created

**connection.js**

```
const neo4jIP = "localhost";
    const neo4jPort = 11001;
    const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
    const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://"+neo4jIP+":"+neo4jPort, 
neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "abc1"));
    var session = driver.session();


var getConnection = function (cb) {
    session.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
      // pass the error to the callback
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, connection);
    });
  };
  module.exports = getConnection;
```

**My query is -**

```
matchQuery = "Match (" + lowerCaseParent + ":" + lowerCaseParent +") where "+ lowerCaseParent +".name ="+  connection.escape(parent) +" ";
        createQuery = "Create  ("+ lowerCaseData  +":"+ lowerCaseData  +"{name:"+  connection.escape(data) +"})";
        relationQuery = "("+ lowerCaseParent +")-[:"+ type +"]->("+lowerCaseData +")";
```

**The query that gets framed is like this where slashes are unwanted-**

```
'Match (naya:naya) where naya.name =\'naya\' Create  (it:it{name:\'it\'}),(naya)-[:Department]->(it)',
  'Match (it:it) where it.name =\'it\' Create  (test:test{name:\'test\'}),(it)-[:System]->(test)',
  'Match (test:test) where test.name =\'test\' Create  (ngoconnectionserviceimpl:ngoconnectionserviceimpl{name:\'ngoconnectionserviceimpl\'}),(test)-[:Function]->(ngoconnectionserviceimpl)'
```

I somehow want to remove slashes from query and it can't be done with -

```
  .replace(/\\/g, '')
```

Comment: Looks like it is escaping the single quotes. Using backslash to escape characters that are meaningful otherwise is very common. If you don't want the escape, why are you using `connection.escape`?

Comment: hi smac, it comes on itself , the escape character. I don't want them . i.e. i don't want  backslash

Comment: connection.escape is used to escape the backslash/ any escape character